# Remove 'A' in appendix "appendix A" in Masterdocotoralthesis document class

Tags: appendix, section-titles

First and foremost, Am using Mastersdoctoral thesis as a document class

My problem is that I have just one appendix and I want to remove the A next to appendix and see my changes in in my table of content, plus I want the counting after appendix to begin from 1, not A.1.

As an example: Instead of this

Appendix A

Chapter's name

I want this:

Appendix

Chapter's name

Comment: Welcome, could you please post an example of your code and packages you are using, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. The answer could depend on your document class, what works for `book` might not work for `memoir` or `scrbook` for example.

Comment: I assume you have only one appendix.  Basically you need redefine either `\thechapter` or `\thesection` to do nothing. (after `\appendix`).